# Payment gateway for flutter

Tags: dart, payment-gateway, flutter

How can I integrate a payment gateway in flutter framework. Is there any libraries I can use readily? Do I need to do it separately in iOS and Android?
In that case which is the best library available in India? 
Check out the new package for making payment
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack

Comment: My client suggest me this website https://www.instamojo.com ,and  I have seen a video for android implementation,

its called Instamojo,in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2x6xlnYnHjc ....A guy just installs and EXE and that adds extra lines in gradle automatically,so i hope if i Choose flutterprojectfolder/android then it will add the same magic for flutter too,but not yet tried,
if my perception is wrong then pls anyboy tell,how to get a raw Android folder(As like Native flutter) Folder, from a flutter folder

Comment: Razorpay has released a fluttter package for their payment services. https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-flutter

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are no payment plugins for flutter yet.

To integrate payments into a flutter app, just integrate payments natively and invoke it by implementing a [platform channel](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/).

An example of platform channel implementation is shown [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel).

Hope that helped!

Comment: Hi Ambareesh, in our app we have integrated upi payments but only received success messages in to flutter app if the payments are done through tez/bhim or paytm but not the other types of upi payments like phonepe etc. Well we have done exactly what Hemanth suggested

Comment: This answer needs some updating because nowadays there are some pay plugins available in 2021: https://pub.dev/packages/pay and https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe .

Comment: We have open source the juspay-flutter sdk We use it in production -https://github.com/deep-rooted-co/juspay_flutter

Answer (score 8):

I was able to integrate stripe using webview & flutter_webview_plugin

```
 String test = "Test Charge";
 int amount = 100;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new WebviewScaffold(
      url: new Uri.dataFromString('''
      <html>
        <head>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        </head>
        <center>
          <body>      
            <form action="Your Server" method="POST">
              <script
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="pk_test_key"
                data-amount="$amount"
                data-name="$test"
                data-description="My Order"
                data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-currency="eur">
              </script>
            </form>            
          </body>
        </center>
      </html>
            ''', mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
    ));
  }
```

you'll need to set up a server for live payments. More info can be found:
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple

Comment: Does this work on iOS for you? As far as I know iOS webview doesn't support keyboard so far.

Comment: Hi, could you help me, I am stuck in an issue related to your answer, @JAAYBone

Comment: how can we implement ccavenu with this method.