# adyen payment integration in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, adyen

Im trying to integrate adyen payment(card payment and iDEAL payment) in flutter but there is no stable plugin or dependency available..please help me by providing any example of the same.

thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023085/7924565

Answer (score 0):

Adyen doesn't provide an official flutter library as of now.

Your best bet would be using something like [webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to load the Adyen js components as a webpage.

Comment: Ok, let's say the payment has gone through using the webview, how will the app know about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64315924/how-can-i-redirect-back-to-flutter-app-from-url this may help